# When would I choose следующий over ближайший?

Tags: выбор-слова

I'm a little confused about the difference in usage between the two.

1. Which is more common?
2. When would I choose the other (less-common) one to describe a 'next' something?

The dictionary definitions don't seem to help — the entry for `ближа́йший` claims (sense two) that it would be used to refer to a '(day, year)  next'; but then the entry for `следующий` uses *that* word instead for 'next year' ("на сле́дующий день".)

Answer (score 4):

*Следующий* means "next". This is literally the following day, week, year and so on:

> - Это отражается на работоспособности на следующий день и на жизненном тонусе в целом.
> - На следующий день я повстречал Шлиппенбаха возле гонорарной кассы.
> - Так что я даже будучи командиром, домой все равно на следующий год попаду.

*Ближайший* means "closest".

In the singular, it's usually used in the sense of "closest available", "nearest available":

> - Ближайший день, на который у них были билеты, наступал ровно через неделю, а именно 30 декабря.
> - Договариваемся на какой-то ближайший день и ездим за город, в один и тот же мотель.

, although it can mean "next" too, especially with larger periods like week, month, or year:

> - Он весь ближайший месяц будет выходить в ночную смену, а мы с девочками будем работать только днем

In the sentence above, you can just replace it with *следующий*.

In the plural, it means "coming", like in "in the coming days":

> - Вешняков высказал мнение, что ситуация в крае будет разрешена в ближайшие дни.
> - Я взял телефон её мужа и обещал связаться с ним в ближайшие дни

Comment: An addition: the best Russian equivalent to _следующий_ is “following”, since it is derived from the verb _следовать_ “to follow”.

Comment: Excellent answer and perfect English!

Comment: @YellowSky You mean English equivalent 

Comment: @CocoPop - That's right, I really don't know why I wrote ‘Russian’, hehe. Perhaps I inserted it later and misses the right place, wrote it before ‘equivalent to’ instead of after that.

Comment: I was wondering why would somebody say *ближайший месяц* instead of *следующий месяц*. I think *ближайшай месяц* is a period of time until the same date in the next month (similar to English *the next month*?). And *следующий месяц* means next calendar month, starting on 1st (English *next month* without article?). Same for years and weeks (except in Russian, weeks start on Monday, not Sunday).

Comment: @il--ya - I'd rather say that the week starts on Monday in _Russia_, not in _Russian_. Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week): “While, for example, the United States, Canada, Brazil, Japan and other countries consider Sunday as the first day of the week, and while the week begins with Saturday in much of the Middle East, the international [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standard and most of Europe has Monday as the first day of the week. The Geneva-based ISO standards organization uses Monday as the first day of the week in its ISO week date system.”

Comment: @il--ya People say «крайний» instead of «последний», so I might imagine «ближайший» instead of «следующий» is not unimaginable.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko Well, *следующий* is often replaced with *очередной*, especially when talking about lockdowns. 

Answer (score 0):

«Следующий» implies (linear) order. Since time is ordered, it's more common to use it with **time** expressions. Another usage is, for example, the next person in line.

«Ближайший» is more common when referring to highest **spacial** proximity: «ближайший магазин», «ближайшая остановка», «ближайший подъезд».

**EDIT**. You can compare usage frequency via Google Ngram Viewer:

- [«cледующая неделя» vs «ближайшая неделя»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%2C+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0)
- [«следующая неделя» vs «ближайшая неделя»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%3B%2Cc0)
- [«ближайший магазин» vs «следующий магазин»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0)
- [«ближайший поезд» vs «следующий поезд»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%3B%2Cc0)

The person in comments mentioned «ближайшее время». «Ближайшее время» is a fixed expression and by itself [constitutes the majority of usages](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%2C+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0) of the word «ближайший» in the corpus. Moreover, it doesn't really contradict my statement since this expression is not about order. It doesn't mean "the next epoch".

Comment: _“В ближайшее время”_ (in quotation marks): 40 million results [in Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q="В+ближайшее+время"&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). _"В ближайшие дни"_ 9.5 million results.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What is your point though?

Comment: The point is, when you write something like “X is more common than Y”, you could add a kind of reference or a proof-link, or anything like that.

Comment: Like [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%2C+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: That is not a proof of anything. You state _ближайший_ is rather about space than about time, or at least I understand your answer this way. If it is so, could you support that statement in a way? The Google results I quoted above say _ближайший_ is as much about time as about space.

Comment: Of course it's not a proof. It's an example. You can't prove anything with mere examples. But since you asked I edited the answer to clarify my point. I'm talking about which word among the two is more often used for a fixed time or space-related noun.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can see that after 3 comments of mine you still fail to understand what I mean. Let me explain it in a different way: -1.